# Android studio App not install to another device, it work only one device that is use by usb

Tags: android

I make a simple project on android studio it work fine on that device which is connected by usb. When i try to share that app from one device to another then it show app not install to another target device. I make build app after that i also share on another target device, it also show same issue. Please tell me.

Comment: Because it is not signed for the another device.

Comment: Android Studio signs the app for the device.

Comment: @KhabyLame: You might want to in detail what you mean by "signs the app for the device".

Comment: It makes a signed apk for the device. The device recognises the app's signed certificate and allows the app to run

Comment: @AmanNarang: How do you "share that app from one device to another"? If you are saying that you are running the app in Android Studio, then taking the APK from the first device and somehow send it to the second device, that will not work. An app run directly from Android Studio via things like the Run toolbar button [are set up for use only from the IDE](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html). However, you can build APKs from the Build menu to get an APK that you can install on other devices.

Comment: @KhabyLame: "It makes a signed apk for the device. The device recognises the app's signed certificate and allows the app to run" -- while apps are digitally signed, that would not prevent an app installed on Device A from running on Device B. The digital signature is for the *app*, not for the device.

Comment: Correct @CommonsWare. I

Comment: As stated by @Commonware that can be the issue, so do check how you are sharing the app, and if the problem still persists then try to give more details like is there any crash or do the device on which you are sharing the app has a copy of app already installed.

It can be issue if the user has a signed apk installed and on top of that he tries to install debug apk then the app will not be installed and shows app not installed or vice versa.